# Populate dropdown with images from folder

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, razor, jqgrid

I use http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick and I wan't to bind my dropdownlist with images from my project folder. There is a lot of images in folder so how I can do this with foreach loop? I use ASP.NET MVC 4 with Razor Syntax

Comment: I get images from folder but I dont' know how to populate dropdown with all my images. I don't wan't to add imgsrc, text and value for every image becasue there is a lot of images in folder. I wanna use foreach loop but I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some sort of paging. Since ddSlick seems does not have build-in support for this (sure you can spend some time and add it yourself), you may want to check **http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2**

Check examples how to add paging with AJAX loading (http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/#ajax) and how to use infinite scrolling (http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/#infinite)

Note: if you need to show results after user try to open combo box (not when user type something inside), you can set minimumInputLength setting to 0. This will emulate dropdown behaviour close to what you get using ddSlick.